# How to change the default package.json location in npm?

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, automated-tests, testcafe

I have a TestCafe test project.
This is the "scripts" portion of `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe chrome tests"
  }
```

When I try to run the npm script, this is what I get:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.1
3 info using node@v13.3.0
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\package.json'
5 verbose cwd E:\
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
8 verbose node v13.3.0
9 verbose npm  v6.13.1
10 error code ENOENT
11 error syscall open
12 error path E:\package.json
13 error errno -4058
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

So, it is complaining about not finding `E:\package.json` which is true, because my project is in `E:\projectName\`.

How can I tell the npm to look for `package.json` in `E:\projectName\package.json`? How come it is not searching for it inside the project folder by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my mistake.

I was starting the script with `npm test` instead of with `npm run test`. Now it is working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`--prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix) option.

In your case:

```
$ npm --prefix E:\projectName\ ...
```